# Split string at commas

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I have some strings in Java, which look like the following:

```
    String s = ""Aac 1Zl Aachen",,DE,5048.850N,00611.483E,189.0m,1,,,,"AACHEN""
```

I wanna split the string at every comma and assign the splitted values to an array. But i couldn't figure out how to keep the empty values between the multiple commas, which should be null.

The resulting array should look like this:

```
    array[0] = ""Aac 1Zl Aachen""
    array[1] = null
    array[2] = "DE"
    array[3] = "5048.850N"
    array[4] = "00611.483E"
    array[5] = "189.0m"
    array[6] = "1"
    array[7] = null
    array[8] = null
    array[9] = null
    array[10] = ""AACHEN""
```

Comment: First you should escape those quotes... and look into String split

Comment: There is no benefit by leaving string quotes as part of the value, or assigning NULL.

Answer (score 2):

You can split by comma and post process the resulting arrays:

```
String[] toks =
       "\"Aac 1Zl Aachen\",,DE,5048.850N,00611.483E,189.0m,1,,,,\"AACHEN\"".split(",");
for (int i=0; i<toks.length; i++) {
    if ("".equals(toks[i]))
        toks[i] = null;
}
```

Comment: I can easily write a regex to take care of quotes but that is not part of question.

Comment: I believe OP couldn't figure out how to keep the empty values between the multiple commas, as `null`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)), method of String and replace empty string with null

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RegFun {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "\"Aac 1Zl Aachen\",,DE,5048.850N,00611.483E,189.0m,1,,,,\"AACHEN\"";
        String[] split = s.split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
            if (split[i].equals("")) {
                split[i] = null;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
    }
}
```

output

```
["Aac 1Zl Aachen", null, DE, 5048.850N, 00611.483E, 189.0m, 1, null, null, null, "AACHEN"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "This is String , split by StringTokenizer, created by mkyong";
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");//split by commas
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure a NULL is a definitive solution since splitting on comma's alone just invites
trouble. Possibly, if Java supports split() using a regex, you could use `\s*,\s*` for it.

Another, better solution, is to use a real csv regex that not only does field trimming,
but takes into account comma's inside of quotes. The latter, if possible, makes using split
untenable.

Since the fields are trimmed, NULL is not necessary as a check, using length as the alternative.
In regex jargin, NULL means the group didn't match anything. In array jargin, as in C/C++,
NULL means a pointer that is not assigned a value.  Using trimming, eliminates ambiguity.

To do it right ...

You could use this as a find all regex. Each value is returned in group 1 or 2.
Just catenate  `$1$2`.

Each field is also trimmed (leading/trailing) of whitespace.

```
 # "\\G(?:(?:^|,)\\s*)(?:\"([^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*)\"|([^,]*?))(?:\\s*(?:(?=,)|$))"

 \G 
 (?:                           # leading comma + optional whitespaces
      (?: ^ | , )
      \s* 
 )
 (?:                           # Cluster group
      " 
      (                             # (1), double quoted string data
           [^"\\]* 
           (?: \\ . [^"\\]* )*
      )
      "
   |                              # OR
      ( [^,]*? )                    # (2), non-quoted field
 )
 (?:                           # trailing optional whitespaces
      \s* 
      (?:
           (?= , )
        |  $ 
      )
 )
```